# Create an SSRS report that can have multiple matrices with different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am attempting to develop a rather complex SSRS report and want to see if this is possible.  Basically, I am trying to create a report that will have multiple pages and each page will have different columns (unknown number of columns, so the report has to be created dynamically).

I have got my dataset to look like this so I can create a matrix so the columns will be generated dynamically: 
[Dataset Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhvnz.png)

That way the column_name can be displayed dynamically at the top of the matrix and I have row groups on row_id and page_id, to get the data under the correct column and to break on the next page.

But the problem I am running into is that when you get to the next page there could be different columns that I don't want to show on page 2.  Those columns do not appear in the dataset for page 2 but - they will still show up on the report - just have blank data for them.   See picture below:
[Report Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OJoB.png)

My question is: Is this possible to do with SSRS? I have a column SLA_ID in the dataset which basically is a report id. Could that SLA_ID be used to define the number and name of columns for each page?  All the report definition data will be stored in the database that I am creating - I just can't figure out how to get SSRS to cooperate with this set of data.

Basically my end result is to have one RDL that can run the same type of report but the report can display different data/columns depending on the client selected.   Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Are you asking can you use 1 data set, to have multiple matrixs in the same report, but have different columns show in each matrix? If so I you should be able to do this using filters on the individual matrices, either tied to logic or variable/logic.

Comment: No one matrix in the report - that can show different columns on each page break

Comment: Yeah I don't think that is possible. maybe if you are really good and edit the XML behind the RDL, but I mean, how would it export? I always think, generally any SSRS will get exported to Excel/CSV, so how could a table have different columns at different points in time. If it is known number of pages/division you might be able to do sub reports, but even then I am not sure if you could do it without 1 per column set.

Comment: Have you already succeeded in creating a 1-page report with a matrix with a dynamic set of columns defined in a dataset like yours?

Comment: You can;t do this in a single matrix control. The [age break are irrelevant really, it's still one big matrix. Basically whatever content you have in your column group field will generate a column and it can't be filtered except at the matrix level so the only way do this is to have multiple matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by nesting a matrix in a table.

Step 1:
Create a table with only one group row on page_id and set it to page break.

Step 2: Create a matrix with row_id on row group, column_name on column group and column_value on values

You design would look like the image below
[image]

Step 3: Insert the matrix inside the table group cell

[image]

Executing the report your result will look like the images below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good advice. The key is that the column headers are in rows in the dataset. You let the report group them on columns for you so that they are dynamic. Because you can't have dynamic column names in a dataset.

Comment: The header row of the table can be easily deleted if not needed

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add another matrix like this.

Step 1 : Go to column groups

Step 2 : Click on down arrow and add group

[image]